# Css3 webkit gradien old syntax

Tags: css, webkit, radial-gradients

I've been experimenting with css3 radial gradients and came up with a nice looking gradient:

```
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center 110%, 80% 100%, transparent 20%, #22853D);
```

Now, I am trying to make it cross-browser. What would be the equivalent of the above for the old  -webkit-gradient('radial') syntax?

**UPDATE**
Simply put it, it is possible to draw an ellipse with the old syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. You could apply a circular radial gradient and then squish it through css transformations, as here: [CSS3 Radial Gradients with RGBA()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464571/css3-radial-gradients-with-rgba/4527735#4527735) but I wouldn't recommend this approach.

I'd recommend using SVG backgrounds, you can generate your own gradient at Microsoft's website:

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/svggradientbackgroundmaker/default.html

It provides excellent coverage across all browsers (they only blind spot being Firefox 3.6).